# FFserver: Securing with HTTP Authentication? (Apache?)

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, webcam, security, ffserver

Is there some way to secure an ffserver webcam stream using Apache / HTTP Authentication?  Some type of Apache proxy perhaps?

Right now I have it so only machines on the LAN can view the http://webcam/stream.mjpg, but I want people from the outside to be able to access it if they provide a username / pw (HTTP Auth, which isn't built into ffserver).

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same case as the above you mentioned but I don't want any authentication i just want people from any network to view the video by using my system's path (address) because right now only machines on lan can view . Can you provide me any idea on this and m using ffserver only.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the solution, I found it:

Use proxy.conf (apache mod-proxy) with directives such as the following:

ProxyPass |external path| http://internal_lan_ip/internal_path

One of mine that works is:

ProxyPass /proxy/matt.mjpg http://192.168.1.10:8090/matt.mjpg

So externally they are going to:

http://myserver.com/proxy/matt.mjpg

And the stream (matt.mjpg) is coming from a different host on the LAN at

http://192.168.1.10:8090/matt.mjpg.

Thus, myserver.com is a "proxy.com" for internal LAN hosts.